# Rational numbers are measure zero

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure, rational-numbers, fake-proofs

> Set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ is measure $0$.

I approach this question by two sides.

(First)
Like here [Showing that rationals have Lebesgue measure zero.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508217/showing-that-rationals-have-lebesgue-measure-zero), $$
\mu(\mathbb Q) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{q_n\}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(\{q_n\}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 0 = 0.
$$

(Second)
Using the definition of Lebuesgue measure. let's order $\mathbb{Q}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\{ r_{i}\right\} $. For given
$\epsilon>0$, cover $\mathbb{Q}$ by $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\{ r_{i}-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}},\ r_{i}+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}}\right\} $(Let this covers $E_{\epsilon}$).
Then $\mu\left(\mathbb{Q}\right)\leq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\epsilon/2^{i}\leq\epsilon$.
So $\mu\left(\mathbb{Q}\right)=0$.

---

Here, I have a question on the second proof. 
If we cover $\mathbb{Q}$ like the second proof, I think the covers $E_{\epsilon}$
cover all real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.

The reason is here : If we let $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$,
for any $\delta>0$, there exists $b\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $|a-b|<\delta$ (by
the density of $\mathbb{Q}$). So $a$ must be in some intervers in
the covers $E_{\epsilon}$. So $\mu\left(E_\epsilon\right)=\infty$ $\forall\epsilon>0$.

What is my fault in my reason?

Comment: How do you infer $a$ is covered from $|a-b|<\delta$? There is no guarantee that $\epsilon/2^{i+1}$ is greater than $\delta$.

Comment: @CaveJohnson There must be rational numbers next to $a$. So I thought so.

Comment: This sort of thing is tricky, it'll take a while to wrap your head around this sort of thing because the picture doesn't feel right to start with. This ends up not covering all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Suppose $\epsilon_i=|r_i-\pi|$ for each $i.$ Is $\epsilon_i\gt0$ for each $i?$ Does your argument prove that the intervals $(r_i-\epsilon_i,\,r_i+\epsilon_i)$ cover all real numbers? All right, which one covers the real number $\pi$?

Comment: @bof no cover covers $\pi$, but I think those covers cover $\mathbb{R}\setminus {\pi}$.

Comment: Sure they cover $\mathbb R\setminus\pi.$ But doesn't ***your argument*** show that they cover $\mathbb R$? For any $\delta\gt0$ there exists $b\in\mathbb Q$ such that $|\pi-b|\lt\delta$ (by the density of $\mathbb Q$). "So" $\pi$ must be in some interval . . .

Comment: @bof Your covers differ from mine.

Comment: You wrote: "If we let $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$,
for any $\delta>0$, there exists $b\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $|a-b| < \delta$ (by the density of $\mathbb{Q}$). So $a$ must be in some intervers in the covers $E_\varepsilon$. So $\mu(E_\varepsilon) = \infty$ $\forall \varepsilon>0$." But it can happen that for every rational number $r_i$, the radius $\varepsilon/2^i$ is less than the distance from $r_i$ to $a$. Thus $a$ will not get covered. $\qquad$

Comment: Yep, my cover is different. Why can't I use the same argument you did, to show that my cover covers every real number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fault in your reasoning is where you claim, without justification, "So $a$ must be in some . . ." Unless you come up with some *reason* for that "so", there is nothing more to be explained here.

Your conclusion is wrong, those intervals do *not* cover $\mathbb R.$ That is clear from measure theory, as you know. In order to give an *explicit* example of a real number which is not covered, we have to know how the rationals are enumerated. Since you did not assume anything special about the enumeration, I can use any enumeration I like. Let me define a special enumeration which makes it easy to exhibit an uncovered number. (Also I will take $\epsilon=1.$)

First, let $q_1,q_2,q_3,\dots$ be your favorite enumeration of the rationals. Now I define a new enumeration $\{r_i\}$ recursively. If $r_1,\dots,r_{i-1}$ have already been defined, then I define $r_i$ to be the *first* $q_j$ such that $q_j\notin\{r_1,\dots,r_{i-1}\}$ and $|q_j-\sqrt2|\gt\frac1{2^{i+1}}.$

**Does the sequence $r_1,r_2,r_3,\dots$ contain all the rationals?**

Since your sequence $q_1,q_2,q_3,\dots$ contains all the rationals, it will be enough to show that each $q_j$ occurs in the sequence $r_1,r_2,r_3,\dots.\ $ I will prove this by induction on $j.$ Suppose that each of the numbers $q_1,q_2,\dots,q_{j-1}$ occurs in the sequence $\{r_i\}.$ Since $q_j$ is rational while $\sqrt2$ is irrational, we know that $|q_j-\sqrt2|\gt0.$ Thus (with $j$ fixed) if we choose $i$ large enough, we will have both $\{q_1,\dots,q_{j-1}\}\subseteq\{r_1,\dots,r_{i-1}\}$ and $\frac1{2^{i+1}}\lt|q_j-\sqrt2|.$ For such an $i$ we will certainly have $q_j\in\{r_1,\dots,r_{i-1},r_i\}.$

**Do the intervals $(r_i-\frac1{2^{i+1}},\ r_i+\frac1{2^{i+1}})$ cover $\mathbb R$?**

No, none of those intervals covers $\sqrt2,$ because $|r_i-\sqrt2|\gt\frac1{2^{i+1}}.$

Comment: Can you please tell me why $\{q_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ contains all rationals?

Comment: I wrote thise answer 4 years ago, so I don't remember anything about it, but I can read it. You're asking about the line that says "Since your sequence $q_1,q_2,q_3,\dots$ contains all the rationals . . .". Four lines above that, I read: "First, let $q_1,q_2,q_3,\dots$ be your favorite enumeration of the rationals." So that's why. The sequence was **assumed** to contain all the rationals. The phrase "enumeration of the rationals" means "sequence containing all the rationals and nothing else."