# Are my calculations of $||f||_{L_{\infty}(E)}$ correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory

I'm trying to calculate $||f||_{L_{\infty}(E)}$ where
$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
 & x, x \in \mathbb{I}\\ 
 & 2x, x \in \mathbb{Q}
\end{matrix}\right.\: \: \: E:= [0,1]
$$

I knew that $E$ had finite measure. Hence I can use following 
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty}||f||_{L_{p}(E)} = ||f||_{L_{\infty}(E)}
$$

My attempt:

$$
||f||_{L_{\infty}([0,1])} = \lim_{p \to \infty}\left(\int_{[0,1]}|f(x)|^{p}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} =
\lim_{p \to \infty}\left(\int_{[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}}|2x|^pdx + \int_{[0,1]\cap\mathbb{I}} |x|^{p}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}} = \lim_{p \to \infty }\left(\int_{[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}}(2x)^{p} + \int_{[0,1]\cap\mathbb{I}} x^{p} \right)^\frac{1}{p}=\lim_{p \to \infty}\left(\frac{2^p + 1}{p + 1} \right)^\frac{1}{p} = 2
$$
Am I wrong? If yes: where am I wrong? How could I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [rationals have Lebesgue measure zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508217/showing-that-rationals-have-lebesgue-measure-zero), so $\Bbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ has measure zero and so you have incorrectly evaluated one integral:
$$  \int_{[0,1] \cap \Bbb{Q}} \dots  = 0  \text{.}  $$
Correct that and your argument is repaired.

A different argument:  $f$ is bounded by $1$ on $[0,1] \cap \Bbb{I}$ (a set having measure $1$) and $f$ is bounded by $2$ on $[0,1] \cap \Bbb{Q}$ (a set having measure $0$).  Therefore, $f$ is essentially bounded (see also [essential supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_spaces#Lp_spaces) of $|f|$) by the former bound, $1$, $||f||_{\infty} = 1$.

The reasoning is the same in both cases -- the bound on the measure zero set does not alter the essential bound.